# How to send bulk email in Django rest framework reading from csv?

Tags: django, csv, email, django-rest-framework

CSV file :

Name     Email                  Phone

---

```
A       aa@gmail.com          11111
B       bb@gmail.com          22222
```

I have a seralizer :

```
class ImportCsvSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     csv = serializers.FileField(required=True)
```

Now I am using :

```
  send_mail(subject,'',settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,[users.email],html_message =html_message,
           fail_silently=False)
```

How can I iterate each row and send multiple emails ?

Comment: How many data in your CSV?

Comment: @a_k_v I have 100 data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are nearly there. Using the `send_mail` you can send out your email to a list of email addresses. As such, do something like:

```
# in models.py or views.py, wherever you access the csv file

recipient_list = []

with self.csv.open(mode='r') as file:

    # add in your dialect, or use the csv sniffer to determine dialect
    f_csv = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # iterate over remainder of rows
    for line in f_csv:

        # determine email address
        email = line[1]

        recipient_list.append(email)

# then you can send your email list using your method.
send_mail(subject,'', settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, recipient_list, html_message=html_message, fail_silently=False)
```

If you can send out text based messages, consider using the method `send_mass_mail()`. This method is a more efficient then `send_mail` as it sends out all emails in one connection, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#send-mass-mail).

Comment: But I have to send different html_message in each email. How can I do that

Comment: In that case you need to ```send_mail``` in each line of the csv, you can't combine it in 1 method.

Which leads me confused as to what your question actually is